# Комментарий на несколько строк Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, комментарии

Смотря различные гайды на ютубе,я видел как люди комментируют несколько строк одним  разом при помощи символа `#`,подскажите,что за комбинация клавиш позволяет это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173118/shortcut-to-comment-out-multiple-lines-with-python-tools-for-visual-studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, а затем <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> комментирует выделенные строки с помощью `#`. <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, а затем <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> убирает комментарий со строк. Если у Вас Mac OS, используйте  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> вместо <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.